# How do i get and use AlignmentHeader from pysam?

Tags: bam, pysam

I need to pull header information from a cram file for use in python code.  This seemed to be a good use for pysam.

however, I can not find **any** pysam sample code that lets you look at the header of an existing file.

pysam has the AlignmentHeader class, but nowhere in the pysam git repository can I find **any** indication of how I would use it, other than creating one to create a file.

Which is not the point.

So, does pysam let you get header information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is:

```
import pysam
cram = pysam.AlignmentFile (theCram, 'rc')
cramHeader = cram.header.to_dict ()
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future